# Connecting Fiscal printer with flutter app

Tags: flutter, printers, fiscal

I'm working on a kitchen app in flutter. So I need to connect different types of printers to get the KOT and customer prints.
I've already connected

1. **EPSON thermal printers**
2. **Starmonics TSP100III**
3. **Bluetooth printers**
4. **SUNMI printers**

But not able to connect **FISCAL** printers. It gets connected with the flutter app via Bluetooth but doesn't take a printout
gives the exception: **Unimplemented/Unsupported command**

Is there any way to connect fiscal printers with flutter app?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try [this](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_printer) but I don't know if it works

Comment: hi @Nio74 I'm already using this Dart package, but it doesn't support fiscal printer :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to implement http Request, this is an Example that I finded this for Printer Epson:

```
A SOAP message is returned as the response to the HTTP POST method. The SOAP body contains the response document. To permit cross-domain communication, the response contains the HTTP "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header. See Fiscal Printer Intelligent Features Guide for browser cross-domain information.


[Example]
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: xxxx
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<response success="true" code="" status="xxxxx" />
</s:Body> </s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi @Nio74, thank you so much for your answer.
Can you please elaborate a bit more, I'm new at this.